# Printing variables indented at different levels at once

Tags: python, indentation

Basic question about indentation, which result is for mere lazy purposes of visual match as the variables are related.

As I am improving my Python skills am constantly finding ways to improve the typing style, and now am wondering if it is possible to `print` to the screen several variables from a function to test that everything is in order before of proceeding with something else. `return` does not do the trick and will not show anything.

For example:

```
    def function(a):
        
        c = []
        
        for key, val in a.items(): 
            b = len(val)
        
            if val % 2 == 0:
                c.append(val)

        print(a.keys(), b, c)
```

This is a very simplified example. Now, my idea was to print the keys from `a` with the count of the values in this dictionary as `b` and those that satisfy the conditional which are `c`.

However, here it is printing the lists of values for `a` and `c`, but `b` is ignored and gives a `0` as is indented inside of the loop. `b` works correctly and gives a result only if the `print` corresponds to the indentation.

```
([1, 2, 3], 0, [1.1, 1.2, 1.3])
```

Comment: Ummm. Are you saying that python is whitespace sensitive?

Comment: I have to admit that I'm confused as is @MadPhysicist.  `b` does have value outside of the loop, this why you're printing `0` instead of `None` or something else (like the interpreter dying because it doesn't exist).  I think you may be stumbling on the fact that outside of the loop `b` will have whatever value was _last assigned to it_.  It seems that the last time the loop ran, `val` had 0 length.

Comment: @AndrewFalanga. There's a close vote for that

Comment: I cannot tell why by now. I also would expect to my knowledge that it gave None maybe, as it's out of the indentation and Python would complain, but also printing that variable `b` it just gives a 0. As example in the correct indentation it gives the correct values of the length of `val` like 1,1,4,230,34,0,0,0,0,0 and zeros at the end as expected. Perhaps the print is giving the last 0?

Answer (score 0):

Like other code, print is impacted by indentation of loops and conditionals.

Here is some more information of how indentation works in Python. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/statement-indentation-comments

Unindented code, outside loop

```
total = 0
for i in range(3):
    i
total += i
print(i)
#2
print(total)
#2
```

Code inside loop

Unindented code, outside loop

```
total = 0
for i in range(3):
    i
    total += i
    print(i)

#0,1,2

print(total)
#3
```

If you want the info to be printed every loop, you need to indent the print statement. Separately, operation len will only work on list-like objects, whilst operation % will only work on numeric objects, so one of len(val) and val % 2 will error in your code.

Comment: Alright, then I must understand it just as a Python property that must be used in this way. In the end in my particular case it was easier to append the information to new lists and in that way I returned 4 lists with the 4 variables of my interest for later processing, but just for printing purposes it's not possible (or necessary).

Comment: Ok yes, collecting records as lists and printing every loop both seem like valid debugging methods to me. It can take some getting used to how whitespace/indentation works in Python.